# Fetching a variable

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, python-2.7, pymssql

I got this code:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT nom FROM productes WHERE listacompra = 1')
producteslc = cursor.fetchone()
```

The problem is that when I do print `producteslc`, it returns `(u'Natillas',)`, when the value on the SQL Database is just Natillas.

What could I do to have a variable with value = Natillas? I'm trying to do some stuff with split but I'm not able to do it at my own.

Thank you

Comment: Futhermore, when there's more than one value with listacompra = 1, it only appears the first one. I'd like to know how can I solve it, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `fetchone` is a tuple of the values of one row.

Since you only fetch a single column, the result is a tuple singleton: `(u'Natillas',)`

To get the string:

```
producteslc = cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

See: [Tuples and Sequences](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) in the doc

**EDIT**

To fetch several rows, you can use `fetchall()` function:

```
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(row[0])
```

To print each name.

Comment: It solves the first question! Thank you so much. Anyway, how could I solve when there's more than one value that accomplish the condition?

Comment: What do you mean by “accomplish the condition”? Any example?

Comment: Now i got a row with nom = Natillas, listacompra = 1 and another one with nom = Chocolate, listacompra = 1. When I run that code, it just returns Natillas. I'd like it to return both.

Comment: Works. Thank you so much. Now, how could I have that names in separate variables?

Comment: @Nico: Not clear what you are asking: “how could I have that names in separate variables?”. A good practice on SO is to [post a new question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318267/1513933).

Comment: @Nico: When you find an acceptable answer, a good practice on SO is to upvote and [accept and answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/344471).

Comment: OK, then I'll do. Thank you!